# In Mathematica, how can I cut off the high-order terms in a polynomial?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

For example, I have a polynomial y＝a_0＋a_1 x + ..... + a_50 x^50. Since I know that the high-order terms are imposing negligible effects on the evaluation of y, I want to cut off them and have something like y＝a_0＋a_1 x + ..... + a_10 x^10, the first eleven terms. How can I realize this?

I thank you all in advance.

Comment: I believe this question belongs to the [Mathematica Stack Exchange site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
In[1]:= y = a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3 + a4*x^4;
y /. x^b_ /; b >= 3 -> 0

Out[2]= a0 + a1 x + a2 x^2
```

Comment: Please explain a bit what is going on here.

Comment: Sure. In the expression y replace (that is the /.) the pattern x^b_ (that is x to any power b) under the condition (that is the /;) that the exponent is greater than or equal to 3 with (that is the ->) zero. So all x^n with n>=3 become zero and 0*an=0 and those terms disappear from the expression.

Answer (score 7):

The mathematically proper approach..

```
  Series[ a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3 + a4*x^4, {x, 0, 2}] // Normal

  -> a0 + a1 x + a2 x^2
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a shortcut to the previous answers which is even more symbolic. You write, say,

```
y[x_] = a0 + a1 x + a2 x^2 + a3 x^3 + a4 x^4 + a5 x^5;
y[x] + O[x]^3
```

which gives you,

```
a0 + a1 x + a2 x^2 + O[x]^3
```

Answer (score 3):

If your polynomial is actually as simple as shown, with a term for every power of `x` and none others, you can simply use `Take` or `Part` to extract only those terms that you want because of the automatic ordering (in `Plus`) that *Mathematica* uses.  For example:

```
exp1 = Expand[(1 + x)^9]

Take[exp1, 5]
```

> ```
> 1 + 9 x + 36 x^2 + 84 x^3 + 126 x^4 + 126 x^5 + 84 x^6 + 36 x^7 + 9 x^8 + x^9
>
> 1 + 9 x + 36 x^2 + 84 x^3 + 126 x^4
> ```

If it is not you will need something else.  Bill's replacement rule is one concise and efficient method.  For more complex manipulations you may wish to decompose the polynomial using `CoefficientArrays`, `CoefficientRules`, or `CoefficientList`.